# Calculation the average of short type array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, primitive, short

Let's say I have a short[] thisArray in JAVA, and I need to calculate the average based on the amount of elements in this array. But apparently, .length will return a int number to represent the length of thisArray.

I cannot convert it into int Array or int, since it is not allowed to convert int back to short. I do need to have a short result and store back into another short[][].

How to avoid this classic error:
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
            short result = sum / thisArray.length;

```
public static short getSum(short[] sumArray) {
  short sum = 0;
  for(short i : sumArray) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

sum = getSum(thisArray);

short result = sum / thisArray.length;
```

Comment: Question: `short sum = 0;` Does the sum of two short ints always fit inside another short int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for sure the average can fit into a short variable, you just have to cast the result:

```
short result = (short)(sum / thisArray.length);
```

I'd also change `sum` to `int`, to reduce the risk of overflow (which may occur if the sum is larger than 32767).

To summarize:

```
public static int getSum(short[] sumArray) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(short i : sumArray) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

...

int sum = getSum(thisArray);

short result = (short) (sum / thisArray.length);
```

Comment: Average of a short array can always fit into short variable, the sum of short array might not be able to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast the result

```
short result = (short)( sum / thisArray.length );
```

The compiler is protecting you from losing data when you assign an `int` value to a `short` variable.  Providing the cast is the usual way of telling the compiler that you know what you're doing, and this operation is OK.